# Android Facebook oAuth - The proxied app is not already installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am doing Facebook oAuth using the new graph api. However, the SDK is set to run in compatibility mode (i.e. making calls to v1.0 endpoints by default).

Every time I try to login, I get a blank screen from Facebook and the following is the exception in logcat:

```
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070): Exception during service
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 408 [message]: The proxied app is not already installed. [extra]: null
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:84)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:163)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:153)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:482)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:183)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.d(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:137)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:281)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:493)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:234)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:360)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:58)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:280)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:58)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue( 1070):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)


<!-- end snippet -->
```

I am asking for the following permissions:

```
    permissions = Arrays.asList( "user_status", "read_stream", "email", "user_friends", "installed");
```

And this is how I am setting the permissions:

```
private void onFacebookLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isClosed()) {
            session = new Session(getActivity());
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
        if (!session.isOpened()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, callback);
        }
    }
```

What does this error mean? Has anyone found a solution yet? Thanks!

Comment: check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070153/facebook-sdk-apiexceptionthe-proxied-app-cannot-request-publish-permissions-w]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I am not requesting any publish permissions at this point. But you could be right, it could be a permissions issue after all.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking a solution for this issue, this is what worked for me:

Check your permissions, it looks like "installed" wasn't a valid permission. After removing "installed" from the list everything works fine.